# Reading file from Dataflow VM to pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a streaming Dataflow Pipeline, in which a file will be generated and stored in path /tmp/filename.txt, I have checked the beam documentation, but it seems there is no IO connection that allows me to read in this file and further process it. The only way that I can think of is to store the file back to GCS and read it in again for the next step process.

Does anyone have a better solution? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Beam provides the `Filesystems` ([java](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html), [python](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.filesystems.html)) package, which is a wrapper of all the various  file systems that a Beam pipeline may have access to. You can use it to consume your file.

For Python your code would look something like this:

```py
path = '/tmp/filename.txt'
f = FileSystems.open(path)
contents = f.read()
```

For Java:

```java
String path = "/tmp/filename.txt";
ResourceId rid = FileSystems.matchNewResource(path, false);
ReadableByteChannel ch = FileSystems.open(rid);
```

You can write that as part of your `DoFn`, and output the file contents that way if you'd like.